# Pagination/404 I believe wp is getting a page ahead of itself

Tags: plugins, pagination, 404-error

My site is using the [Faceted Search Widget](https://github.com/FCC/Faceted-Search-Widget/tree/develop) upon reaching an archive page. The widget works fine provided you stay on the initial archive page, but if I try using it on the second page of the archive it works only if there are 8 or more entries to return, third page only if there are 16+.

It almost seems as though when wp is figuring out what page it's on it's one ahead of itself. [Here is a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kbqKUdxu) of my archive page. Any thoughts as to why this is happening/how to fix it?

Pastebin with the [faceted-search-widget](http://pastebin.com/JctTtUSn)

Answer (score 1):

Using `query_posts` is not advised anymore and in your instance, using it outside of a page template will cause strange results, `query_posts` is used for altering the main loop of your site, therefore its advised to use something like `WP_Query` instead.

Replace from line 14 of your code:

```
<?php
        //bad: do not use query_posts
        global $query_string;
        query_posts("{$query_string}&posts_per_page=8");
        if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
```

With this,

```
<?php
        //good: use WP_query instead
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 8, 'paged' => $paged));
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
```

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately that doesn't appear to have made any difference. I've updated the pastebin to reflect your suggestion as well as added another pastebin for the plugin itself. http://pastebin.com/JctTtUSn I noticed "paged" doesn't appear anywhere within the plugin, could that be part of the issue?